# linux + create host file from CSV file by sed or awk or perl

Tags: linux, perl, sed, awk

I have the following CSV file

this file defined which Linux machine exist in the system and there ip's

my target is to create host file from this file

please advice how to create host file as example 1 from my CSV file ( I need to match the IP address from CSV file and put it on the first field of the host file , then match the LINUX name and locate this name in the sec field – as example 1 )

remark - should be performed by sed or awk or perl .. , I need to write the solution in my bash script

CSV file

```
    , machine , VM-LINUX1 , SZ , Phy ,  10.213.158.18 , PROXY

    , VM-LINUX2 , SZ , 10.213.158.19 ,

    OLD HW , VM-LINUX3 , SZ , 10.213.158.20 ,

    , VM-LINUX4 , SZ , Phy ,  10.213.158.21 ,

    , VM-LINUX5 , SZ , Phy , OUT , EXT , LAN3 , 10.213.158.22 , INTERNAL 

    , VM-LINUX6 , SZ , Phy ,  10.213.158.23 ,

    , server , new HW , VM-LINUX7 , SZ , Phy ,  10.213.158.24 , OUT, LAN3

    , VM-LINUX8 , SZ , 10.213.158.25 ,

    OLD HW , machine , VM-LINUX9 , SZ , Phy , INT , 10.213.158.26 , LAN2, AN45, 

    , VM-LINUX10 , SZ , Phy ,  10.213.158.27 ,

    , VM-LINUX11 , SZ , Phy ,  LAN5 , 10.213.158.28 ,
```

example 1 ( host file )

```
    10.213.158.18 VM-LINUX1
    10.213.158.19 VM-LINUX2
    10.213.158.20 VM-LINUX3
    10.213.158.21 VM-LINUX4
    10.213.158.22 VM-LINUX5
    10.213.158.23 VM-LINUX6
    10.213.158.24 VM-LINUX7
    10.213.158.25 VM-LINUX8
    10.213.158.26 VM-LINUX9
    10.213.158.27 VM-LINUX10
    10.213.158.25 VM-MACHINE8


    10.213.158.26 STAR9
    10.213.158.27 TOP10
    10.213.158.28 SERVER11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat file | perl -ne '/(\w+-LINUX\w+).*\s([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})/;print "$2 $1\n";'`

Comment: Last question is it possible to set argument in the perl syntax , for example in place LINUX to write $LINUX , and then set LINUX=MACHINE1 or LINUX=LINUX100 ?

Comment: no, '$' have different meaning in regular expression syntax.
It's a oneliner - just replace '-LINUX' with any string you want

Comment: but what I can do if I have allot of different names ( for example in place of LINUX could be other different names ) ? can perl one linear support this ?  ( see also my update in my quastion )

Comment: If your hostnames are not common pattern, are in different columns  and you have no idea how to formalize script requirements - it's probably better to just open csv with oocalc or something and edit it manually

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne 'print "$1 $2\n" if m/(VM-LINUX\d+).*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/;' < /PATH/TO/your.csv
```

or (if not even the order of the two fields is determined)

```
perl -ne 'print "$1 " if m/(VM-LINUX\d+)/; print "$1" if m/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/; print "\n";' < /PATH/TO/your.csv
```